# spring form tags uri cannot be resolved in web.xml or jars deployed with this application

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, taglib, spring-form

I am working on java web project (maven) and used spring. Everything worked fine with spring, till I used spring form tags. While running jsp, error pops, 
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**

 I am giving code from files as follows:

### pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sd</groupId>
  <artifactId>springMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
 <!--  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springdemo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
  
  <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/springdemo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springdemo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

### form.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form path="student" action ="handleForm">

<form:label path="" value="Enter your personal information"></form:label>
<form:input path="name" /><br>
<form:label path="" value="Gender"></form:label>
Male:
<form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"/><br>
Female:
<form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female"/><br>
<form:label path="" value="Age"></form:label>
<form:input path="age" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form:form>

 </body>
</html>
```

### springdemo-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   
   <!-- Adding Support for Component Scan -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.springMVCcontroller" />
   
   <!-- Configure View Resolver -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
 
   </beans>
```

### myWebInitializer.java

```
package com.springMVCcontroller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    public MyWebInitializer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {ConfigClass.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

### configClass.java

```
package com.springMVCcontroller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.springMVCcontroller"})
public class ConfigClass {
        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
        {
            InternalResourceViewResolver ivr=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            ivr.setPrefix("/view/");
            ivr.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return ivr;
        }

}
```

Comment: Ditch the `web.xml`. You either use `web.xml` or a `WebApplicationInitializer` but don't use both. In your case it is worse because your `web.xml` forces you down to the level of Servlet API 2.4 instead of 3.x.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for taking efforts to make things correct. I have removed web.xm as well as dispatcher servlet. Error remains same.

Comment: Does your application even start Spring? As I suspect your jar is borked OR you are using a too old servlet container.

Comment: Everything worked fine with spring, till I used spring form tags. I am doing this to learn spring. I did all basics like autowired, bean class, dependency injection, and also web-mvc things over here. All worked fine with jsp html form.